# Attempting to initialize AWS EB, getting 'signature not yet current error'

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I'm on my local machine. I'm a dev guy with no idea about ops. After selecting `us-east-1` for my region after running `eb init` on the command line, I get this:

```
ERROR: The current user does not have the correct permissions. 
Reason: Operation Denied. Signature not yet current: 
20150922T194753Z is still later than 20150922T194701Z (20150922T194201Z + 5 min.)
```

I've looked around for answers and it appears it's a time zone issue experienced by others **after** their applications are already deployed and they solved the problem by syncing the time zones of their already launched EC2 instances. But, I haven't deployed to EB yet, and I don't have an associated EC2 instance. I tried aligning my system clock and time zone to us-east-1's time zone using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` but the error persists.

So how do I get past this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not a timezone issue. If it was a timezone issue, then the time difference would be in increments of hours rather than minutes.

Your system clock is 5 minutes, 52 seconds ahead of Amazon's clock, which is greater than the variance allowed by Amazon's signature algorithm (5 minutes).

Compare your system time against a known good reference, such as http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/ and set your clock correctly. Most likely, you'll see that your clock is 6 minutes ahead.

If you set your clock 6 minutes back, your commands should execute correctly.

Comment: To set clock correctly, launch this comman : sudo hwclock --hctosys

Answer (score 0):

Set your system clock *and time zone selection*, on your local machine, correctly.